# UML aggregation in OCL

Tags: uml, aggregation, diagram, ocl

[UML Diagram for given problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9965184/Obrazy/OCL%20-%20Link%20to%20StackOverflow.png)

I have been given a task to create pre and post conditions for an operation:

```
getInformation(givenTitle:String):Integer
```

The operation should return a number of all bug reports for a project of a specified title. As for the pre conditions i have figured out the following:

```
context Company::getInformation(givenTitle:String):Integer
    pre: has->size() > 0 and has->exists(title = givenTitle);
```

Yet I have a big problem how to handle the aggregation of artifacts in projects

If it was just an association I would do the following:

```
    post: has->select(title = givenTitle)->first().Artifact.relatedTo->size() = result;
```

But I don't know how to handle the aggregation, and i can't seem to find any useful information about that on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreggation is not an autonomous UML element, it's just a **kind of bidirectional association** (with a "shared" end), so everything that applies to an association is valid.

Same goes for the composition, only the end is "composite").

And a small correction - I noticed that you use association names in OCL expressions ("has", "relatedTo", etc). To be fully complient with OCL specification, you should use the **association ends' role names** instead.